# Laravel + Vue router - Best practice for slugs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a laravel + vue app. I've created a vue spa application for a particular page called shop. In this shop, I have 3 sub pages which is about, products and contact.

routes.php

```
Route::get('/shop/{slug}/{vue_capture?}', 'ShopController@show')->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

vue-router.js

```
export const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Home, name: 'home',
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'about',
        component: About
      },
      {
        path: '/products',
        name: 'products',
        component: Product
      },
      {
        path: '/contact',
        name: 'contact',
        component: Contact
      } 
    ]
  },
];
```

So for example I go to domain.com/shop/joe-shop, what is the best practice to extract the slug and use it in my vue application so I can make http requests with slug parameter to server? Thank you

note: I'm also using vuex state management in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var slug = window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/shop\/([^\/]+)(?:\/.*)?/i,'$1');`

**Note:**

With your current set-up, you would need to set the `base` property in your vue-router config to behave properly.

```
new Router({
    base: window.location.pathname.replace(/^(\/shop\/[^\/]+).*/i,'$1'),
    mode: 'history',
    routes: ...
})
```